# Colisión de figuras en java con canvas Jframe

Tags: java, array, canvas, jframe

Tengo este proyecto en java, el cual permite crear figuras a base de puntos, utilizando canvas, jframe y Vector para almacenar los puntos o figuras; también me permite crear más figuras y poder moverlas con las teclas de movimiento.
[image: Para mover al figura tengo que seleccionarla en el cuadro de texto y desde ahí moverla]

Para no hacer tanto texto, estoy tratando de que cuando una figura choque con otra figura, esta se detenga. Por lo que tengo entendido crear un cuadrado imaginario para que al momento de que un objeto choque con otro, la función de movimiento se detenga de ejecutar.

Función del cuadrado imaginario

```
 private boolean chocar(int fig){
    puntosAux=(Vector)figuras.elementAt(fig-1);
    for (int r = 0; r <puntosAux.size(); r++){
    punto =(Point)puntosAux.elementAt(r);
    Vector puntosFigComp=new Vector();
    for (int nFig = 0; nFig < figuras.size(); nFig++){
        if (nFig != fig-1){
            puntosFigComp=(Vector)figuras.elementAt(nFig);
            int x1=500, x2=0, y1=500,y2=0;
            for(int t=0; t < puntosFigComp.size(); t++){
                Point puntosAux = new Point();
                puntosAux=(Point)puntosFigComp.elementAt(t);
                if(puntosAux.x<x1) x1=puntosAux.x;
                if(puntosAux.x>x2) x2=puntosAux.x;
                if(puntosAux.y<y1) y1=puntosAux.x;
                if(puntosAux.y>y2) y2=puntosAux.x;
            }
           if (punto.x>x1 && punto.x<x2 && punto.y>y1 && punto.y<y2){
               System.out.println("Choco con la figura " + ((int)nFig+1));
               return true;
            }                
        }
    }
}
    return false;
}
```

Función para mover la figura

```
    public void moverFigura(int fig, String dir) {
    if (puntos.size() > 0) {
        figuras.addElement(new Vector(puntos));
        puntos.clear();
    }
    puntosAux = (Vector) figuras.elementAt(fig - 1);

    if (dir == "Lef") {
        for (int r = 0; r < puntosAux.size(); r++) {
            punto = (Point) puntosAux.elementAt(r);
            punto.x = punto.x - 5;
            puntosAux.indexOf(punto, r);
        }
        figuras.indexOf(puntosAux, fig - 1);
    }
    if (dir == "Right") {
        for (int r = 0; r < puntosAux.size(); r++) {
            punto = (Point) puntosAux.elementAt(r);
            punto.x = punto.x + 5;
            puntosAux.indexOf(punto, r);
        }
        figuras.indexOf(puntosAux, fig - 1);
    }
    if (dir == "Down") {
        for (int r = 0; r < puntosAux.size(); r++) {
            punto = (Point) puntosAux.elementAt(r);
            punto.y = punto.y + 5;
            puntosAux.indexOf(punto, r);
        }
        figuras.indexOf(puntosAux, fig - 1);
    }
    if (dir == "Up") {
            for (int r = 0; r < puntosAux.size(); r++) {
                punto = (Point) puntosAux.elementAt(r);
                
                punto.y = punto.y - 10;
                puntosAux.indexOf(punto, r);
            }

            figuras.indexOf(puntosAux, fig - 1);
        
    }
    this.repaint();
}
```

Por lo que tengo entendido tendría que llamar la función *chocar*, para que al momento de que una figura choque con cuadro imaginario, la función de movimiento se desactive, pero no sé cómo mandar a llamarlo.